# Emulator issue in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, amd-processor

**issue:**
**Your CPU does not support required feature(VT -x or SVM).**

when am creating an emulator in my computer facing this issue, how can I resolve this issue?

I am using a Windows2008 PC; I have AMD A4-6320 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics 3.80GHZ processor.
In my Control panel > Programs and features there is no Hyper-V feature. How to install HAXm on my computer?
 For android studio emulator, the AMD processor is supported or not?
 can anyone solve this ?

All are saying about intel system am using AMD processor can you tell me about AMD processor?

Comment: if virtualization isnt supported - you could simply run on a device. All modern CPU though support it. check your bios settings

Answer (score 0):

Please check this video [How to install HAXM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9QG8VMxpt8)

Also if you couldn't find the HAXM in the SDK Manager, then download it from 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

After that you have to enable VT-X from The BIOS, check this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3irpIFya_lk

Comment: I am using AMD A4-6320 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics 3.80GHZ processor computer. In this computer how can i install intel HAXM, and while am installing intel HAXM it is getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

VT is Virtualization Technology. It is processor capacity. Google your processor model that have or not VT support.

If support! You need to enable VT from bios. To do so
1. Restart your computer
2. Press F2 when you computer boot
3. Find Intel Virtualization Technology and enable it
4. Save and exit by pressing F10

Then Run emulator in android-studio

if any problem please fell free 
good luck..

I google it for you that your cpu has VT [red your processor specification](http://products.amd.com/en-us/search/APU/AMD-A-Series-Processors/AMD-A4-Series-APU-for-Desktops/A4-6320-with-Radeon%E2%84%A2-HD-8370D/28)

so try the step i describe i hope it will be ok...

Comment: He is not going to find Intel Virtualization Technology but SVM (because he has an AMD processor).

Comment: I am asking about non-intel processor system. Like AMD processor am using.

Answer (score 0):

With an AMD processor and on Windows you have 4 options:

1. Run the emulator using an ARM image (quite quite slow)
2. Use another emulator as can be Genymotion. Warning about Genymotion: There is a free version which has limited functionality of the phone and there is a paid version that allows full control of the device.
3. Use an actual device instead of the emulator
4. Activate the SVM Mode from the BIOS (as others have already commented). To do that:

You have to restart your machine.

Enter in the BIOS (usually pressing F2 or Del).

Look up the SVM or Secure Virtual Mode and enable it!